# Firefox keep playing audio after MODAL window close - How to solve?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

ON chrome it works just fine, but on Firefox whenever the pop up close, the audio keep on playing in the background.

Can anyone pls help to resolve this?
10x,
Udi

```js
var mobileDetect = new MobileDetect(window.navigator.userAgent);

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myModal").on("hidden.bs.modal",function(){
     $("#iframeYoutube").attr("src","#");
  })
})

function changeVideo(vId){
   var iframe=document.getElementById("iframeYoutube");
  iframe.src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+vId+"?autoplay=1&modestbranding=1&rel=0&showinfo=0";

if (mobileDetect.mobile()) {
    window.location = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + vId;
return;
  }

   $("#myModal").modal("show");
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">

 <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><a href="#"><span aria-

hidden="true" style="color:white">&times;</span></a></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      
        <iframe id="iframeYoutube" width="700" height="394" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/e80BbX05D7Y" 

frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

That should fix your problem, seems a little bit tricky, but with that the video will be reloaded after closing the modal causing it, surely, to be closed:

```
$("#myModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $("#myModal #iframeYoutube").attr("src", $("#myModal #iframeYoutube").attr("src"));
});
```

Comment: 10x but i dont understand where exactly in the code it should be placed.  i have tries several options, before, after or instead of    $("#myModal").modal("show");
and it influence at all on the firefox browser.  it keeps playing the audio....  pls advice.

Comment: Well... the results are quite poor, sorry to say. what ever i do, it stops the audio just a second after closing the pop up, and than the audio start over...  here is the code as i put it.  pls help.  10x      $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#myModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
   $("#myModal #iframeYoutube").attr("src", $("#myModal #iframeYoutube").attr("src"));
 });
  $("#myModal").on("hidden.bs.modal",function(){
     $("#iframeYoutube").attr("src","#");
  })
})

Comment: another strange issue is that on chrome it dosen start to play automatically, even i i make the autoplay 1, but on the second activation it does play it.  on firefox on the other hand, it works good on that part.

Comment: no my friend delete your own handler. Try this: `$(document).ready(function(){ $("#myModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) { $("#myModal #iframeYoutube").attr("src", $("#myModal #iframeYoutube").attr("src")); }); ` and add the expression for showing the modal in the `documen.ready` handler.

Comment: HHH i just looked at your profile :-)   i already tried to delete the old handler, btw.  was one of my attempts to check whats wrong.  it dosent solve the problem i describe.  after closing the window the audio restart it self after a 1-2 seconds on the background.  :-(  not nice.  10x!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178482/discussion-between-udi-h-keller-and-ths).